# How to setup DNS using zpanel

Tags: domain-name-system, vps, hosting

I am trying to use the DNS features of zpanel and the documentation seems sparse. I had some DNS entries setup on my VPS using WHM / cPanel before my server crashed and now I'm trying to move everything I'm responsible for over to a new server using zpanel instead.

Under cpanel, I had 2 name servers created through WHM: ns1.mathteamhosting.com and ns2.mathteamhosting.com. All web sites that I hosted just listed these name servers when they registered the name and somehow it just worked.

With zpanel, I don't see one main server controling everything else. It is as if each domain name can have it's own name servers. How do I use the DNS feature and set things up as they were before?

I do have a couple of sites up under zpanel, but I needed to explicitly list the IP address of my server using Godaddy's DNS control.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about managing systems using tools designed for end users, not professional systems administrators.

Comment: Related: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3425/ (basically "Using the control panel isn't "professional system administration" - talk to zpanel about their lousy docs.)

Comment: My VPS is in production and runs a few web sites and web services for some non-profit organizations. There are other questions about WHM, DNS, and zPanel on serverfault, so it's not clear why this question was put on hold as off-topic. I am not a "cpanel user." I have command line access to the VPS and was previously providing cPanel accounts to a few customers. Now I am providing them with zPanel and ftp accounts instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actualy you can not have your own DNS with Zpanel.

If you use Godaddy, You should change nameservers of your domains to default godaddy nameservers. After do that, you should point every your domain by advanced DNS zone setting tool (godaddy -> domain management -> dns) to your VPS static ip as a A record.

That is it!

Comment: Yet, there are some DNS setting in Zpanel which lead me to believe that it could help me set up my own nameservers the way that WHM cPanel does. But since I was unable to figure out how to get any of that working, I did exactly what you suggested.